# EXCEPTION: object instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that requires a connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I searched for the solutions in some of the questions that resembles this problem, but couldn solve it, so kindly provide a clear idea about how to solve this.

```
Order orderDetails= createOrder();
long voucherId = (long)orderDetails.Vouchers.FirstOrDefault().Number;  // exception here..
```

and the createOrder function returns the orderDetails of type Order.

Vouchers is my voucher table,

Number is a column's name in the voucher table.

I have no idea, why how to solve this exception. Any idea about it ?
**PART I :**
**EDIT:**

```
private Order createOrder()
    {
        IList<OfferInfo> offerInformation = new List<OfferInfo>();
        OfferInfo offer = new OfferInfo()
        {
            OfferId = 2,
            Message = "test msg",
            CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now,
            Gender = "male",
            ReceiverName = "john",
            ReceiverEmail = "ebenezar@gmail.com"
        };
        offerInformation.Add(offer);

        Order order = new Order();
        order.Id = 721;
        order.Amount = 1000;
        order.CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        order.User = userDetails;
        return BLOrder.CreateOrder(order, offerInformation);
    }
```

**NOTE:**
It inturns call the CreateOrder from the BLOrder which returns the retrieved data in Order type. ( if var is of Order type and is returned, it will have something like, var.xxx="some value" , var.yyy="some value"..)

**PART II:**

```
public static Order CreateOrder(Order order, IList<OfferInfo> offerList)
    {
        order = CreateNewOrder(order, offerList);
        Intreat.MSMQ.MSMQHelper.AddOffers(order, offerList);
        return order;
    }

private static Order CreateNewOrder(Order order, IList<OfferInfo> offerList, bool updateUser = true)
    {
        try
        {

           if (updateUser)
            {
                VerifyUserDetails(order.User);

                senderUserId = BLUser.UpdateUser(order.User);
                order.User = null;
                Logger.WriteLog("Sender user added/updated successfully. UserID:" + senderUserId.ToString());
            }
            else
                senderUserId = order.UserId;

            if (order.Company != null)
                order.CompanyId = BLCompany.UpdateCompany(order.Company).Id;

            VerifyOrderDetails(order, offerList);

            using (IntreatEntities intreat = new IntreatEntities())
            {
                foreach (OfferInfo offer in offerList)
                {
                    orderAmt = (double)((from po in intreat.PartnerOffers
                                                  where po.Id == offer.OfferId
                                                  select po.Price * offer.Quantity).ToList()).Sum();
                    order.Amount += orderAmt;

                    if (offer.IsPos)
                        tableOrderAmt += orderAmt;
                }
                if ((tableOrderAmt > 0) && (order.TipPercentage != null) && (order.TipPercentage.Value) > 0)
                {
                    double tipAmt = (tableOrderAmt * (order.TipPercentage.Value * .01));
                    order.TipAmount = Math.Round(tipAmt);
                    order.Amount = (double)(order.Amount + order.TipAmount);
                }
                order.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                order.UserId = (Guid)senderUserId;
                Logger.WriteLog(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "order.TableNumber:{0}", order.TableNumber == null ? "(empty)" : order.TableNumber.ToString()));

                intreat.Orders.AddObject(order);
                intreat.SaveChanges();

                Logger.WriteLog("Order added successfully. OrderId:" + order.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            }
            return order;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.WriteLog(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your `createOrder` function. My bet is it uses a `DbContext` that you then dispose, then you're trying to get the sub-items of your returned database item (which in turn is trying to call the database).

Comment: @mattytommo : posted. I am able to access the values in the OrderDetails (see very first line of code). But exception occurs in the second line.

Comment: Yeah that's because the `OrderDetails` have been loaded into memory, yet it's child item hasn't. You're going to have to show your `BLOrder.CreateOrder` function too.

Comment: expand orderDetails and check if it has got IsLoaded property for Vouchers true

Comment: @tariq : hi tariq, i checked the IsLoaded property. It is false. What to be done ?

Comment: @Ebenezar_Gislen_Softwares Before the `return order` you need to call `Order.Vouchers.Load` or something similar to make sure they're loaded.

Comment: @mattytommo : i am getting the 'same exception' for this, order.Vouchers.Load();

Comment: very strange if that happens within the using block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

incorporate this line of code **order.Vouchers.Load();**    as done below and try

```
private static Order CreateNewOrder(Order order, IList<OfferInfo> offerList, bool updateUser = true)
{
    try
    {
        Guid? senderUserId = null;

        /// Process user first so that, the user details are stored even if there is any error in other areas
        /// 
        if (updateUser)
        {
            VerifyUserDetails(order.User);

            /// Create/update sending user.
            /// 
            senderUserId = BLUser.UpdateUser(order.User);
            order.User = null;
            Logger.WriteLog("Sender user added/updated successfully. UserID:" + senderUserId.ToString());
        }
        else
            senderUserId = order.UserId;

        /// Add company details before processing the order, so that the company details are stored if there is any error in other areas.
        /// 
        if (order.Company != null)
            order.CompanyId = BLCompany.UpdateCompany(order.Company).Id;

        /// Verify and process order
        /// 
        VerifyOrderDetails(order, offerList);

        using (IntreatEntities intreat = new IntreatEntities())
        {
            /// Find total amount for the order
            double orderAmt = 0;
            double tableOrderAmt = 0;

            order.Amount = 0;
            foreach (OfferInfo offer in offerList)
            {
                orderAmt = (double)((from po in intreat.PartnerOffers
                                              where po.Id == offer.OfferId
                                              select po.Price * offer.Quantity).ToList()).Sum();
                order.Amount += orderAmt;

                //If isPos, consider for tip calculation
                if (offer.IsPos)
                    tableOrderAmt += orderAmt;

            }

            //check if tip amount has to be calculated, by checking for the tableorderAmt
            if ((tableOrderAmt > 0) && (order.TipPercentage != null) && (order.TipPercentage.Value) > 0)
            {
                double tipAmt = (tableOrderAmt * (order.TipPercentage.Value * .01));
                order.TipAmount = Math.Round(tipAmt);
                order.Amount = (double)(order.Amount + order.TipAmount);
            }
            order.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            order.UserId = (Guid)senderUserId;
            Logger.WriteLog(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "order.TableNumber:{0}", order.TableNumber == null ? "(empty)" : order.TableNumber.ToString()));

            /// Create and save order in db
            /// 
            intreat.Orders.AddObject(order);
            intreat.SaveChanges();
            order.Vouchers.Load();
            Logger.WriteLog("Order added successfully. OrderId:" + order.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
        return order;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.WriteLog(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooh! that exception is gone (now the IsLoaded property is true). Thanks man !!

Comment: i have one more question, when i try to access some values like ,
long voucherId = (long)orderDetails.Vouchers.First().OfferId; ,
It says that'Sequence contains no values'. But actually there is a valid record in the Voucher table.. Whats the problem ?

Comment: do you expand vouchers here and there u find a record ?

Comment: i dont think so that vouchers will be having any record here.

Comment: first() throws exception when it does not find the match , you can use firstOrDefault which returns null and not exception

Comment: used firstordefault. Now it says that object reference not set to an instance of an object. (But there is a row in the Voucher table that has values.)

Comment: not in voucher table, it should be visible when you expand Vouchers in visual studio HERE  --> =(long)orderDetails.Vouchers.First().OfferId; Vouchers here will not have anything in your case which means that there is no record in Vouchers which is related to your orderDetails.

Comment: i checked in VS. there are values in orderdetails, but Voucher has no values (in the statement). Why is it not loaded when there are values in the table. Am i missing out something that should be done in order to pulll out the values ?

Comment: if there is a related record for orderDetails in Vouchers then the solution is same ----> when you get this orderDetails at that time like done earlier do ---> orderDetails.Vouchers.Load();